# Maven equivalent to the Ant's propertyfile option

Tags: maven-2, properties, maven, pom.xml

sorry for lamer question, but I really could not found subject. 
I have a external to the pom.xml file, say backup.properties, and would like it load by next mvn run.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated

Oleg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Properties Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/):

> The Properties Maven Plugin is here to
>   make life a little easier when dealing
>   with properties. It provides goals to
>   read and write properties from and to
>   files, and also to set system
>   properties.
>
> It's main use-case is loading
>   properties from files instead of
>   declaring them in pom.xml, something
>   that comes in handy when dealing with
>   different environments.

**Usage:**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
            <file>etc/config/dev.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
       </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the [Properties Maven Plugin](http://haroon.sis.utoronto.ca/zarar/properties-maven-plugin/).